# Python class with default attribute factory

Tags: python, dictionary, object, attributes, overriding

I want to create a python class that executes a certain method whenever an attribute is accessed that does not exist. The final goal is to create an object that loads attributes from the file system if they have not been loaded already.

My current idea is to replace the `__dict__` attribute with a `defaultdict` and to override the `__getattr__` method with a method accessing the `__dict__` attribute. This looks like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = defaultdict(lambda: "Now we would load and return the object...", 
                                    self.__dict__)
        self.attribute = "An attribute"

    def __getattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__.__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The desired behaviour is as follows:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.attribute
'An attribute'
>>> a.non_existent_attribute
'Now we would load and return the object...'
```

As far as I can tell, this works. I am now wondering what the hidden costs of this procedure are and whether there is a more elegant way to implement it.

- Can overriding `__getattr__` be expected to have a major impact on computational performance?
- Is there a possible implementation that only jumps in if an error is raised because an attribute does not exist? (Then the object would not behave differently when existing attributes are acccessed.)
- Will now the defaultdict be considered whenever an attribute is accessed or are there other ways to access attributes that I missed? (Is this implementation going to cause errors if it replaces a usual object?)
- Are there risks associated with this approach that I may have missed?

Comment: What is the purpose of this seemingly unnecessary meta-ish programming? Why not just have a plain dictionary that maps attribute names (strings) to whatever?

Comment: @KentShikama As I said, the attributes shall be loaded from the file system only if they are accessed. The loading functionality is not yet included in the example. The class is meant to be used as a base class for other classes.

Comment: You could just update the dictionary using the file system every time a key isn't found in it. I'm confused because since you're loading attributes from the filesystem, you've already lost most static analysis ability so it feels pointless to try to allow your object attributes to pretend like they are statically defined. But don't mind me, I could just be lacking imagination as to how this would be useful.

Comment: @KentShikama The attributes shall be loaded on first access and then stored in memory. The idea is that MyObject is a very large object and the time for loading it completely is saved, because some attributes may never be used.

Comment: Who decides which attributes are allowed, the file system (lookup on the disk) or the program (fixed list of attributes)? If this is the program, you could use a `@property` and a plain dict (as @KentShikama wrote). If this is the disk, why not just use the `__getattr__` to try to load an atribute and update manually `self.__dict__`?

Comment: You don't need a `defaultdict` for this; define `__getattr__` to use `setattr` to create an instance attribute the first time the attribute is accessed.

Comment: @jferard The object will contain a list of attribute names that can be loaded from the disk. This list will be generated dynamically when the object is saved and loaded before the individual attributes are loaded. I would not like to hard-code which properties are loaded from the disk but rather automatize the process.

Comment: @chepner This makes sense. However, is it clear that the `__dict__` attribute will never be accessed by other methods?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't worry about that; directly accessing `__dict__` violates whatever encapsulation `__getattr__` is trying to maintain anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler definition that doesn't require changing the value of `self.__dict__`:

```
class MyClass():    
    def _load_attribute(self, name):
        """Load value for attribute <name> from disk"""

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        value = self._load_attribute(name)
        setattr(self, name, value)
        return value


m = MyClass()
print(m.foo)  # Calls m._load_attribute("foo") from m.__getattr_ to set m.foo
print(m.foo)  # Accesses m.foo directly, without calling m.__getattr__
```

`__getattr__` is only called for attributes that aren't found via the normal lookup algorithm; once `setattr` is called, the attribute *will* be found normally, so `__getattr__` will only be called once per attribute.